# Update specific column in MySQL from CSV

Tags: mysql

I am looking to import data from a CSV file into MySQL. The CSV is roughly 100 lines and looks as follows.

```
data1,num1
data2,num2
```

The MySQL database looks as follows.

```
<th>aaa </th>|<th>b</th>|<th>c</th>|<th>...</th>|<th>ggg</th>|
----|-|-|---|---|
<td>data</td>|<td>*</td>|<td>*</td>|<td>...</td>|<td>num</td>|
```

What I am looking to do is find `data1` in the MySQL table and replace `num` with `num1` on that line, and to do this for each line in the CSV.

My database knowledge is on the lower end so any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE

Here is where I am sitting at now. I cannot seem to get this to update more than the first line from the .csv file.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempTable; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable
(`data` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `num`  varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE tempTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

UPDATE DBTable t1
JOIN tempTable t2 ON t1.data = t2.data
SET t1.num = t2.num;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable;
```

Comment: You need to load to a staging table then update to your table.

Comment: Are you sure your `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` is correct? Sounds like MySQL is importing the first row and not able to find the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You could load CSV file into a new table, then extract data with a JOIN.

Create a temporary table; try to use for `data` same data type you have on your table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_table_csv` (
  `data` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `num`  bigint(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Then load CSV into this new temporary table; we suppose your CSV file has columns header.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'csvfile.csv'
  INTO TABLE `temp_table_csv`
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Then make a JOIN and write into a file.

```
SELECT `sx`.`data`, `dx`.`num`
  FROM `temp_table_csv` AS `sx` INNER JOIN `datatable` AS `dx`
    ON `dx`.`data` = `sx`.`data`
  INTO OUTFILE 'newcsv.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

At last you can remove temporary table previously created.

```
DROP TABLE `temp_table_csv`;
```